# Update a document field with multiple nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nested-documents

I have an existing MongoDB document that contains the field `files`(as well as other fields). The `files` field is an object and now I want to update this field with several nested documents. I have been successful in inserting one nested document with the following syntax:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { "id": 1 },
    {
        $set: {
            "files":
            {
                "filename1": {
                    "a": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                    "b": "Sit amet consectetur",
                    "c": "Adipiscing elit"
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Next, I tried inserting 2 more documents at the same time into the `file` field which failed

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { "id": 1 },
    {
        $set: {
            "files":
            {
                "filename2": {
                    "d": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                    "e": "Sit amet consectetur",
                    "f": "Adipiscing elit"
                }
            }
{
        "filename3": {
            "g": "Duis aute irure",
            "h": "Labore et dolore",
            "i": "Eiusmod tempor incididunt"
        }
    }
}})
```

After this didn't work, I attempted to insert the records one by one using the first code block, but inserting `filename2` (I did not want to overwrite existing `filename1`). This document was inserted into the `files` object but overwrote the existing document `filename1`. I tried several different variations but nothing has worked.

Any feedback/assistance regarding how to nest several documents within a field would be helpful.

Comment: Your second query has syntax issues, please check below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because your update query has few issues, check this :

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { "id": 1 },
    {
        $set: {
            "files":
            {
                "filename2": {
                    "d": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
                    "e": "Sit amet consectetur",
                    "f": "Adipiscing elit"
                },
                "filename3": {
                    "g": "Duis aute irure",
                    "h": "Labore et dolore",
                    "i": "Eiusmod tempor incididunt"
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Above query would work but there is an issue here - it would replace the existing `files` field with the new `files` being sent since you're using `$set` which would replace the existing field with new value(If old value is different compared to new value).

If `files`is an array you can use `$push` or `$addToSet` to add new values to existing `files` field(Then you would just replace `$set` with one of these it will work), but if you wanted to have `files` as an object, either your need to read it and inject new values using `.` notation in code & write the whole `files` back to MongoDB using `$set`, which is two calls to DB. In the other way you can do it in one DB call by this :

```
db.updateObject.updateOne({"id": 1}, {
    $set: {
       /** Same like programming language you use `.`,
           You're not replacing files rather you're adding new objects to files,
           If 'files.filename2' already exists in DB then it would be updated. */
        'files.filename2': {
            "d": "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "e": "Sit amet consectetur",
            "f": "Adipiscing elit"
        }, 'files.filename3': {
            "g": "Duis aute irure",
            "h": "Labore et dolore",
            "i": "Eiusmod tempor incididunt"
        }
    }
})
```

Which would update the `files` object with two new objects in it :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e179dac627ef7823643cd97"),
    "id" : 1,
    "files" : {
        "filename1" : {
            "a" : "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "b" : "Sit amet consectetur",
            "c" : "Adipiscing elit"
        },
        "filename2" : {
            "d" : "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "e" : "Sit amet consectetur",
            "f" : "Adipiscing elit"
        },
        "filename3" : {
            "g" : "Duis aute irure",
            "h" : "Labore et dolore",
            "i" : "Eiusmod tempor incididunt"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, appreciate your help!